# Redirect с некоторых ip адресов

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-7, iis-7

Есть [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) приложение которое крутится на [iis-7](/questions/tagged/iis-7), сайт доступен по адресу http://localhost/site1. *Отрефакторил* приложение(исправил небольшие косячки, добавил функционал), теперь хочется предоставить его для *тестирования* некоторым пользователям.

На сервере [iis-7](/questions/tagged/iis-7) создал новый сайт: http://localhost/site2, куда разместил *обновленную* версию приложения.
Возможно ли сделать при доступе к *site1* пользователей на основании списка `ip` перенаправлять на *site2*.

Comment: Есть для iis модуль для revers proxy. Если не нужен именно redirect то можно его рискнуть применить. Может быть есть возможность выбирать конечный сайт на основе ip посетителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, проще всего сделать это при помощи модуля IIS [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), в котором создаем правило на базе заданных IP.

Вот пример правила, которое на основании определенного IP адреса перенаправляет пользователя на другой адрес:

```
<rule name="Redirect by IP" stopProcessing="true">              
     <match url=".*" />
           <conditions>
              <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10.10.10.*" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/site2" />
  </rule>
```

Если адресов не много, что можно перечислить их в условиях:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
         <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10.10.10.5" />
         <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="20.20.30.15" />
         <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="30.30.20.44" />
</conditions>
```

Если адресов много, то можно использовать [Rewrite Maps](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect by IP" stopProcessing="true">              
         <match url=".*" />
               <conditions>
                  <add input="{IPList:{REMOTE_ADDR}}" pattern="1" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/site2" />
      </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
      <rewriteMap name="IPList">
           <add key="10.10.10.5" value="1" />
           <add key="20.20.30.15" value="1" />
           <add key="30.30.20.44" value="1" />
           <add key="40.40.40.2" value="1" />
       </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
 </rewrite>
```

Comment: а можете подсказать можно ли *инвертировать* правило, т.е. сделать обратное правило для site2 что бы всех остальных редиректить на site1?

Comment: @Bald как вариант, можно в последнем примере добавить negate="true": <add input="{IPList:{REMOTE_ADDR}}" pattern="1" negate="true" />. А в url соответственно site1.